# How do I submit feedback on the ubuntu font?

Tags: ubuntu-font-family

I've joined the Ubuntu Font Family Interest Group and I'd like to provide feedback on the mono beta font, or, at least see if other people have reported the same issue I'm seeing.

What's the best way to engage with the ubuntu font folks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are reporting a bug or problem with the font, you should file it [in Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-font-family/+filebug). Otherwise, you could [ask a question on this page](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-font-family/+addquestion).

Comment: **@Davious:** Yes, @George is correct.  Please use the bug tracker or answer track links above to file your feedback.  The "Ubuntu Font Folks" are not strangers, and you are most welcome to get in contact directly with myself or another member of the design team.  We've been asking that people use the beta fonts for a week in their normal daily usage in order to filter out "kneejerk"-type reactions and hunches from genuine issues that still need to be investigated.  I look forward to your feedback (or even just suggestions about how to make the bug tracker links more obvious).

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu Font Family had its own [wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubuntu%20Font%20Family) and there you can find that the project is hosted on [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-font-family) for tracking bugs and wishes and there is also the [Ubuntu typeface interest page](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-typeface-interest) on launchpad.

Comment: Thanks. I feel bad because I read that wiki page and did not discern that the way to engage with the font designers was through that Launchpad project. I joined the font interest group. After I read the groups home page, I was confused because there was no launchpad bugs/answers options for the interest group. Of course, the home page had a link to the wiki page which has the engagement information I missed. It all makes sense to me now.

Comment: No problem! And keep the accepted vote on George. He needs the rep more than I do >:-D